# Titles before text

Tags: spacing, sectioning, formatting

I'm writing study notes using LaTeX. I'd like to introduce each section with a title describing what I'm going to discuss. I dont want: the text to be boldtype, the title to come in numbered. Is there any way of achieving this? Oh, and also, I'd like to have the title and main text nicely spaced. Here is an example of what I'm currently doing, i.e. I'm using the center environment, along with vspace.[image]

My code:

```
\begin{center} This is what I'd like to have \end{center}
Find more information about how to ask a good question here. Visit the help center. Ask questions about the site on meta
\vspace{2mm}
\begin{center} This is what I'd like to have \end{center}
Find more information about how to ask a good question here. Visit the help center. Ask questions about the site on meta
```

Comment: You should take a look at the `titlesec` package for that.

Comment: I had come across that package while searching for a way. But I didn't find anything that achieves what I describe in the Original Post.

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: I only tried what I show in the picture + code, because all codes using titlesec package have numbered, bold and uncentered titles and those three features are not what I'm looking for.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. It's up to you to select the correct parameters for `\titleformat`. Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: you mean, this one? https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf. If so, yes. I read it earlier today, but perhaps I'm too slow to figure out by myself what I should do.

Comment: @campa: Never had any problem with it. Of course, documentations are not supposed to be skimmed.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}%
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\filcenter\Large\scshape}{}{0ex}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{10ex}{6ex}

\begin{document}

\section{ This is what I'd like to have}
Find more information about how to ask a good question here. Visit the help center. Ask questions about the site on meta.

\section{This is also what I'd like to have}
Find more information about how to ask a good question here. Visit the help center. Ask questions about the site on meta.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep! Any way of having non-capitalized words?

Comment: Quite easily: remove `\scshape` (the title is not capitalised *stricto sensu* – it uses smallcaps).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest sticking to the basic markup since it allows you to change things in the future in a global (easy) way rather than having to find every `\begin{center}`...`\end{center}` construction to change something.

Below I use [`sectsty`](//ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) to change the formatting/style of the sectional headings and remove the section numbering. From there, `\section{...}` still prevents being orphaned at the bottom of a page, while your `center` construction could be separated from its content.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\normalfont\large}% Section font styling
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}% Remove section numbering
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{This is what I'd like to have}
Find more information about how to ask a good question here. 
Visit the help center. Ask questions about the site on meta

\section{This is what I'd like to have}
Find more information about how to ask a good question here. 
Visit the help center. Ask questions about the site on meta

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks! but I tested you code and the title appears on the left instead of in the center.

Comment: @dekees: Indeed! If you want it in the middle/centered, add `\centering` to my `\sectionfont` declaration. That is, `\sectionfont{\normalfont\large\centering}`.